# javascript in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Hello I'm trying to use some javascript built in functions inside jade but I get an error.
Here is the code:

```
 - each post in posts
           li(class: 'user-') #{post.created} #{post.body} #{post.title} #{post.tags} #{post._id}
             - var tags = post.tags
             - tags.split(' ')
             - each tag in tags    
           li(class : 'tags') #{tags.tag}
```

I get the error : `Object tag1,,,,,,,,tag2 has no method 'split'`

Comment: tags is a string inside an array called posts

Comment: try `- console.log(typeof tags)`. what does it output in command line?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mixing tabs and spaces.  Jade.js strongly follows the 2 space convention, and tabs ofetn mess up the parser.  Removing the tabs everything works fine for me.

```
- each post in posts
  li(class: 'user-') #{post.created} #{post.body} #{post.title} #{post.tags} #{post._id}
   - var tags = post.tags.split(' ')
   - each tag in tags
     li(class : 'tags') #{tags.tag}
```

And the Javascript to render the .jade file.

```
var jade = require('jade');

var options = {
    locals: {
        posts:[{
                created:'today',
                tags:'1 2 3'
          }]    
    }
};

jade.renderFile(__dirname + '/each.jade', options, function(err, html){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(html);
});
```

Just make sure you are passing in a `tags` variable to the local variables.